# Xcode 6.1 iOS 8 App Icon appearing on top left corner of first screen, unable to be moved or deleted

Tags: ios, xcode, springboard

When I install my app on a device using xCode 6.1 and iOS 8, the app icon appears on the top left corner of the first screen, under an existing app icon, and is unable to be moved or deleted, though I can tap it since it peeks out from under the other icon. Is this a known bug? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Xcode 6.1 simulator works for me. Sounds like a bug. Report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: This is on a real device, not in the simulator.

Comment: Then that's definitely a bug. No apps should overlap on a real device! I suggest you report it.

Comment: Hi, this is definitely a bug and I have it too since a few month (iOS 8), did you fill a radar for it ?

Comment: I think it was due to too many apps on my device. I deleted some apps and have been okay ever since. I did not file a radar for it. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I just filled a bug report to Apple